# Chatter Document Previewer - Have to refresh multiple times to preview document

Tags: visualforce, chatter, contentdocument

We are using `Salesforce Chatter Document Previewer` to view files.

Code in VF page:

```
<div>
    <embed src="/_swf/190003/sfc/flex/DocViewer.swf"
           flashvars="shepherd_prefix={!$Site.Prefix}/sfc/servlet.shepherd&v={!contentId}&mode=chatterfilepreview&in_tests=false"
           width="100%" style="height:100vh;" align="middle" id="renditionLarge" 
           quality="high" bgcolor="#f3f3f3" name="renditionLarge" 
           allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" allowfullscreen="true" 
           pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" 
           wmode="opaque" 
           type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
</div>
```

The document is not appearing right away.
We are getting the message

> Processing File
>
> Refresh

[image: Processing file (Refresh)]

Sometimes we have to refresh up to 20 times to be able to view the document. And other times it takes only one refresh.

Any solution to this issue? The users don't like that they have to refresh to be able to view the document.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of contentID use RecordID(or Document Version ID). It worked for me.

Comment: contentId is actually the record Id. I just named the variable as 'contentId'.
This is an old issue. Got it sorted.
Thanks for replying anyway.